# Onde estão os erros de sintaxe?

Tags: python, sintaxe

eu sou novo em Python e o professor está passando as aulas rápidas demais. Apesar de ser rídiculo, eu estou com dúvida no que está errado no código abaixo. Acredito que a lógica (básica) não está muito errada, mas eu estou completamente perdido na sintaxe. Se puderem me ajudar, agradeço muito! O objetivo do programa é descobrir quantas petecas seriam destruídas. Ele vai receber a soma total da quantidade de petecas que três amigos possuem, dividir pela quantidade de amigos e ver quantas petecas restarão. Esse resto é a quantidade de petecas que seria destruída, para evitar que os amigos briguem.

```
def destruir_petecas(num_petecas, num_amigos = 3):
    """Escreva a instrução
    
    >>> destruir_petecas(91)
    1
    """
    pass

    destruir = destruir_petecas % num_amigos
    print (destruir)
  
print(
    destruir_petecas(91),
    destruir_petecas(91,7),
    destruir_petecas(91,7),
    

)
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema está nesta linha:

```
destruir = destruir_petecas % num_amigos
```

Repare que você está usando a função `destruir_petecas` no cálculo, mas o correto é usar o argumento `num_petecas`:

```
def destruir_petecas(num_petecas, num_amigos = 3):
    return num_petecas % num_amigos
```

Também retirei o `pass`, que não faz sentido estar ali. Ele serve para indicar uma "operação nula", ou seja, ele não faz nada - [veja a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement) para mais detalhes.

E fiz a função retornar o valor em vez de imprimir, pois aí quem chamou a função que faça o que quiser com o retorno (podendo inclusive imprimir, se quiser). Imprimir o valor dentro da função e depois tentar imprimir fora é redundante.

E como a função só retorna o valor do cálculo, nem precisa guardá-lo em uma variável, pode retornar direto.

Answer (score -2):

Não está errado, mas existe uma diferença entre *imprimir* a resposta e *retornar* a resposta:

```
print(destruir)
return destruir
```

O primeiro comando mostra na tela o conteúdo de `destruir` e o segundo, devolve à linha que chama a função o valor de `destruir`,

```
print (
    destruir_petecas(91),
    ...
)
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354782/176034